# How to scan ports asynchronously?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tcpclient

I am trying to work out how to scan a range of ports very quickly but after few hours I'm ready to give up.

I have searched for results on the web but no matter what I do I can't scan the ports fast.

How to do this correctly? Small snippets related to my question are really appreciated.

This is what I have (notice I have a line `allDone.WaitOne(1000, true);` which creates a timeout for the connection. With it timeout slow down the check when IP is down, with out it I don't have enough time to get the result)

```
private void btnScan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (i = (int)nudFrom.Value; i < nudTo.Value; i++)
    {
        ScanPort(IPAddress.Parse(txtIP.Text), i);
    }
}

private void ScanPort(IPAddress address, int port)
{
    using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
    {
        allDone.Reset();

        client.BeginConnect(address, port, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), null);

        allDone.WaitOne(1000, true);

        if (client.Connected) txtDisplay.AppendText("Port: " + i.ToString() + " is open." + Environment.NewLine);
        else txtDisplay.AppendText("Port: " + i.ToString() + " is closed." + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}

public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

public static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    allDone.Set();

    using (TcpClient s = (TcpClient)ar.AsyncState)
    { }
}
```

Comment: Why not parallelize this task? this will greatly increase scanning speed.

Comment: Might want to check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3025486/238902). It involves threading the connections to improve the speed. Did you try to google for "fast port scan C#"? In the Google I use there are a bunch of links based on that. You can even substitute "fast" for "quick"

Comment: @Default, "fast port scan C#" in google return in a first place my previous question from which I got an idea of asynchronous tcpclient :)

Comment: @HelpNeeder there is more than 1 result in Google.

Comment: [Try](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial142_Creating-a-Port-Scanner-with-Csharp.html) [one](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial142_Creating-a-Port-Scanner-with-Csharp.html) [of](http://www.kbcafe.com/articles/HowTo.PortScan.CSharp.pdf) [these](http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/31366-c-simple-port-scanner-in/) [perhaps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331902/c-sharp-tcp-port-scanner-resources)[.](http://www.dijksterhuis.org/building-a-simple-portscanner-in-c/)

Comment: @Default, thanks. I will have a read.